# Linux: Reading the contents of text file and file retrieval from the mentioned subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the names of subdirectories in a text file and these subdirectories are in a base directory. I am trying to read the file and have a FOR loop to go into each subdirectory mentioned in the file and fetch the SQL scripts. However, I'm facing an issue where only the first line of file is read and only the SQL scripts from first subdirectory is retrieved.
Is there any way to iterate over each of the mentioned subdirectory and fetch all the required files.

Below code gives only the first subdirectory mentioned in names.txt file

```
base_path="base_path"
file_name="names.txt"

cd $base_path

echo "Contents of the $file_name file:"
cat $file_name

# Check if the file exists
if [ -f "$file_name" ]; then
  # Read and print each line using a for loop
   for line in $(cat "$file_name"); do
   find ${base_path}/$line -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.sql -exec cp '{}' ${base_path} \;
   done
else
  echo "File not found in Base Directory: $base_path/$file_name"
fi
```

Comment: Assuming that `${base_path}/$line` (which should be quoted, in case you have spaces in the name) denotes a directory, `find` processes all plain sql-files in this directory and copies them to `$base_path` (again, quoting advisable). I would for debugging add the options `-iv` to `cp`.

Comment: Unless `$base_path` is `.` or an absolute path, `find ${base_path}/$line` while your current directory is already `$base_path` cannot work. Remove `cd $base_path`, maybe. Note: `for line in $(cat "$file_name"); do` should rather be `while read -r line; do ... done < "$file_name"`. And you should quote `*.sql` to prevent its expansion by the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
base_path="base_path"
file_name="names.txt"
cd "$base_path"
mapfile -t list < "$file_name"
find "${list[@]}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sql' -exec cp {} . \;
```

`mapfile` populates indexed array `list` with the content of file `"$file_name"`, one line per cell. `find "${list[@]}"` searches with all `list` entries as starting points. This should work even if you have spaces or tabs (but not newlines) in your directory names.

Comment: Thanks Renaud! This is working. However, I have another problem here.
How do I skip intermediate subdirectories in find command. The location of subdirectories mentioned in the text will be : base_path/ **random_dir** /sub_dir1. I want to skip this random_dir while using find command

Comment: @Praveen Well, if you don't have these intermediate subdirectories listed in your `names.txt` file, `find` will not search them. But of course, if they are listed in `names.txt`, they will be searched for. It's up to you. So, if you want `random_dir/sub_dir1` to be searched but not `random_dir`, just put `random_dir/sub_dir1` in `names.txt` and not `random_dir` alone.

Comment: The problem I have here is that "random_dir" keeps changing everytime. So I was wondering if there is any way to bypass this intermediate directory and check directly in sub_dir1. 
More like, **find base_dir/*/sub_dir1**

Comment: Your problem is a bit under-specified, I am afraid: what if there is a `base_dir/sub_dir1/sub_dir1/sub_dir1` directory? Shall `base_dir/*/sub_dir1` match `base_dir/sub_dir1`? or `base_dir/sub_dir1/sub_dir1`? or `base_dir/sub_dir1/sub_dir1/sub_dir1`? All of them? Some of them? Note that this change from your original question is quite significant. Consider, maybe, asking a new question with a complete, minimal and verifiable example.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. As I started to implement the above solution, I stumbled upon this problem. 
To clarify, there would be only one intermediate subdirectory (always). So, it would be just base_dir/random_dir1/sub_dir1 and I want to surpass **random_dir1** everytime there is a search for **sub_dir1**

Comment: Please edit your question and add all the missing pieces, or open a new question. Q&A are not just for your own benefit, they are supposed to be useful to others with similar problems. If the detailed explanation is a mixture of your question and comments it is far less usable and searchable.